# Why Write-host from ps1 is not shown in console?

Tags: powershell

I have a dictionary and a foreach that outputs that dictionary, both inside a ps1 file, which I run with `.\MyScript.ps1`

```
$tokenColors = @{ 
  "None" = "White";
  "Comment" = "Black";
  "Keyword" = "Black";
  "Command" = "DarkCyan";
  "Parameter" = "Black";    
  "Operator" = "Gray";    
  "String" = "Gray";    
  "Number" = "Gray";
  "Type" = "DarkGreen";
  "Variable" = "DarkGreen";
  "Member" = "DarkGreen";    
}

foreach ($token in $tokenColors.Keys) {
  Write-Host "${token}: $($tokenColors[$token])"
  Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind $token -ForegroundColor $($tokenColors[$token]) -BackgroundColor DarkGray
}
```

This does not output any text. Why? (Pasting the code directly in the terminal yields the expected result, but from a script, it does not)

```
PS dev:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.122
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.122
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

PS dev:\> (Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).version
10.0.10586
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: OS and PowerShell version just to be safe?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10 Home 64-bit and PS 5

Comment: There's no reason this shouldn't work. Works fine for me. No output at all or just not what you expected?

Comment: setting the colors works (the Set-PSReadlineOption part) but i have no output (the Write-Host part does not show in the terminal as it does when i run the code directly in the terminal as opposed to running the script with the code)

Comment: hmm, now it works for me too. i have restarted the terminal and rerun the script in a fresh terminal. it is true that, before, i started the terminal, run previous version of the script (that did not have the wrote-output) added my write-output calls and then rerun the script (and no, i did not forget to save the script) ; is there any sort of caching on scripts in the terminal or some sort of buffer for the ps ise?